# installing google chart library on the server

Tags: php, linux, apache, charts

I just copied the library folder on the root directory of my net server . i.e. /var/www .

and used

> require ( 'GChartPhp/gChart.php' ) ;

in my code on the file graph.php. 
ERROR : But, for some reason , the browsers do not load this (graph.php) file .

However, I did the same on my local wamp server and my I am able to run the file.
I have no idea what I need to additionally do for this linux / apache server .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the [**`include_path`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) is not configured the same way on your two servers : you might have to add either the WAMP equivalent of `/var/www` or `.` to it.

Modifying the `include_path` can be done by editing your `php.ini` file, or using [**`set_include_path()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) at the beginning of your scripts.

Another possible solution would be to use an absolute path to the file you are including -- which can be done using something like this :

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/GChartPhp/gChart.php';
```

Notes :

- [**`__FILE__`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) will correspond to the full path to the file in which you write it
- And using [**`dirname()`**](http://fr.php.net/dirname) on it will get you the path to the directory which contains that file.

Which means that this line will use an absolute path... but written relatively to the file in which you put that line.

Comment: So I just need to add this line to the start of my file? I did and is still not getting read.. The weird thing on the web server(linux, apache) is that the page gets redirected to "The page appears broken" .. but it works on my wamp localHost